# Fixing responsiveness of a breadcrumb

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
.breadcrumb input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.breadcrumb input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

.question-header input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.panel-body input[type="radio"]~label {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 0;
}

.panel-body input[type="radio"]:checked~label {
  background: #6FA8DC;
  color: white;
}

.breadcrumb {
  background: black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1px;
  padding-right: 18px;
}

.breadcrumb a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  padding: 5px 30px 5px 30px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
  margin-right: -17px;
}

.breadcrumb a#last {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 0px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 0px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 0px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 0px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
}

.breadcrumb a:hover {
  color: white;
  background: #369F00;
}


/* first link should not have anything cliped on the left side */

.breadcrumb a:first-child {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%);
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.label {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="breadcrumb">


  <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#inviteModal" id="invite-breadcrumb">
    First
  </a>

  <a href="#" data-bind="css:{selected:applicationsFilter() === 'new'}">
    <label class="radio-inline" data-bind="css:{selected:applicationsFilter() === 'new'}">
      <input type="radio" value="new" data-bind="checked: applicationsFilter, css:{selected:applicationsFilter() === 'new'}" class="radcss" name="app" id="newapp">
      Second
    </label>
  </a>

  <a href="#" data-bind="css:{selected:applicationsFilter() === 'shortlisted'}">
    <label class="radio-inline" data-bind="css:{selected:applicationsFilter() === 'shortlisted'}">
      <input type="radio" value="shortlisted" data-bind="checked: applicationsFilter, css:{selected:applicationsFilter() === 'shortlisted'}" class="radcss" name="app" id="shortapp">
      Third
    </label>
  </a>

  <a href="#" data-bind="css:{selected:applicationsFilter() === 'connected'}" id="last">
    <label class="radio-inline" data-bind="css:{selected:applicationsFilter() === 'connected'}">
      <input type="radio" value="connected" data-bind="checked: applicationsFilter, css:{selected:applicationsFilter() === 'connected'}" class="radcss" name="app" id="connapp">
      Fourth
    </label>
  </a>

</div>
```

When the window size is big enough it works fine as below:

[image]

But when I shrink the window size, it becomes ugly as hell. 
Please help me with making it responsive and neat. I also want to remove that black background that appears when I shrink it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use @media (max-width: 408px) { .class{ }} it will helpful for you and I updated your fiddle [check the updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q3vLeht0/4/)

try to use webkit filter in your .breadcrumb

```
@media (max-width: 408px) { 
     .breadcrumb {
            background: none;
             -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 0px black)
        drop-shadow(1px -1px 0px black)
        drop-shadow(-1px 1px 0px black)
        drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0px black);
      filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 0px black)
        drop-shadow(1px -1px 0px black)
        drop-shadow(-1px 1px 0px black)
        drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0px black);
            }
}
```

```css
    .breadcrumb input[type="radio"] {
        display: none;
    }

    .breadcrumb input[type="checkbox"] {
        display: none;
    }

    .question-header input[type="radio"] {
        display: none;
    }

    .panel-body input[type="radio"] ~ label {
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .panel-body input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label {
        background: #6FA8DC;
        color: white;
    }

    .breadcrumb {
        background: black;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 1px;
        padding-right: 18px;

    }

    .breadcrumb a {
        display: inline-block;
        background: white;
        padding: 5px 30px 5px 30px;
        position: 6elative;
        min-width:50px;
        text-decoration: none;
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
        margin-right: -17px;
    }

    .breadcrumb a#last {
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 0px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 0px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 0px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 0px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
    }

    .breadcrumb a:hover {
        color: white;
        background: #369F00;
    }

    /* first link should not have anything cliped on the left side */
    .breadcrumb a:first-child {
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%);
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%);
        padding-left: 20px;
    }

    .label{
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
   
    @media (max-width: 408px) {
      .breadcrumb a {
        display: inline-block;
        background: white;
        padding: 5px 30px 5px 30px;
        position: relative;
        min-width:40%;
        border:1px solid black;
        text-decoration: none;
          -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%);
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%);
        padding-left: 20px;
        margin-right: -17px;
    }
  .breadcrumb a#last {
         -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%);
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%);
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
      .breadcrumb {
        background: none;
         -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 0px black)
    drop-shadow(1px -1px 0px black)
    drop-shadow(-1px 1px 0px black)
    drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0px black);
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 0px black)
    drop-shadow(1px -1px 0px black)
    drop-shadow(-1px 1px 0px black)
    drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0px black);
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="breadcrumb">


  <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#inviteModal" id="invite-breadcrumb">
    First
  </a>

  <a href="#" data-bind="css:{selected:applicationsFilter() === 'new'}">
    <label class="radio-inline" data-bind="css:{selected:applicationsFilter() === 'new'}">
      <input type="radio" value="new" data-bind="checked: applicationsFilter, css:{selected:applicationsFilter() === 'new'}" class="radcss" name="app" id="newapp">
      Second
    </label>
  </a>

  <a href="#" data-bind="css:{selected:applicationsFilter() === 'shortlisted'}">
    <label class="radio-inline" data-bind="css:{selected:applicationsFilter() === 'shortlisted'}">
      <input type="radio" value="shortlisted" data-bind="checked: applicationsFilter, css:{selected:applicationsFilter() === 'shortlisted'}" class="radcss" name="app" id="shortapp">
      Third
    </label>
  </a>

  <a href="#" data-bind="css:{selected:applicationsFilter() === 'connected'}" id="last">
    <label class="radio-inline" data-bind="css:{selected:applicationsFilter() === 'connected'}">
      <input type="radio" value="connected" data-bind="checked: applicationsFilter, css:{selected:applicationsFilter() === 'connected'}" class="radcss" name="app" id="connapp">
      Fourth
    </label>
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to get rid of that black background though?

Comment: I just want it to disappear. And just show the arrow-bar.

Comment: just you can change background property to none like this 'background:none'. I updated my answer check now

Comment: Awesome! Do you know how to add a border in each arrow-bar when it's shrink? I tried to add it but it doesn't work

Comment: Thank you sir! It really helped!

Answer (score 2):

Further to *Udhay* answer. Listing 2 links that might help you further. You could have it as [multi-step](https://codyhouse.co/gem/css-breadcrumbs-and-multi-step-indicator/)

[DEMO](https://codyhouse.co/demo/breadcrumbs-multi-steps-indicator/index.html)

Resize and see how each work. Hope it helps you in the future.

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]